# Is AC necessary here?

Tags: equivalence-relations, axiom-of-choice

I was trying to prove this statement:

> Let $f:X\to Y$ a surjective map and $g: X\to Z$ such that $$\forall\,x,y\in X: f(x)=f(y)\implies g(x)=g(y).$$ Then exists a unique map $h:Y\to Z$ such that $g=h\circ f.\,\,(\ast)$

using the Axiom of Choice, as follows.

Since $f$ is surjective, the fiber $f^{-1}(\{y\})$ is non-empty for each $y\in Y$: thanks to AC, exists a choice function $\sigma: Y\to X$ such that $\forall\, y\in Y: \sigma(y)\in f^{-1}(\{y\})$. Now, $h:=g\circ\sigma$ satisfies $(\ast)$ because $$\forall\,x\in X: h(f(x))=g(\sigma(f(x)))=g(x)$$ since $f(\sigma(f(x)))=f(x)$ from its definition and the hypothesis on $g$. Moreover, if $h':Y\to Z$ satisfies $(\ast)$, we can conclude that $h'=h$: in fact, for all $y\in Y$ we have that $$h'(y)=h'(f(\sigma(y)))=g(\sigma(y))=h(f(\sigma(y)))=h(y).$$

I'd like to understand if my use of AC is correct and necessary because I actually struggle a lot to find when I do need it and when not... For example, I suspect it is necessary here because we don't know if $Y$ is finite and there's no common property among the fibers of $f$ that allows me to pick a particular element from each one *at the same moment*. Any help on the question -- and tips on the proper use of AC in general -- is appreciated!

Comment: Not really topology...

Comment: You say that $h$ is a function because we can find $x\in X$ such that $f(x)=y$ for all $y\in Y$, since $f$ is surjective -- if we call $z:=g(x)\in Z$ then $z\in h$. Assume $z'\in Z$ is such that exists $x'\in X$ with $f(x')=y$ and $g(x')=z'$: we have that $f(x')=y=f(x)$ and so $z'=g(x')=g(x)=z$.

Comment: There might be some foundations of mathematics where this might not be considered a true statement.  The idea being that if the proof of $f$'s surjectivity is not constructive, then $h$ might not be a computable function.  For example, I conjecture that in Coq with no additional axioms, this would not be a provable statement.  However, it *would* be provable with an additional axiom such as an "axiom of unique choice", or using a "unique epsilon" operator.  As it happens, unique epsilon and axiom of unique choice do hold in the internal logic of an elementary topos.  But enough tangents...

Comment: @bianco : I am amazed that this question seems very similar to my own, and SE indicates mine seems to have been independently asked a few hours _after_ yours.  I didn't know about your question but I have  now upvoted your question and the Asaf answer. Can I ask what is the motivation of your own question?  In my link I explain how mine was related to a question from a week ago where I wrote some comments and notes, my question from yesterday (very similar to your own on the same day!)  is here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4457269/defining-a-function-without-using-axiom-of-choice

Answer (score 3):

Since we can assume $g$ is a surjection as well, it's really not about functions. It's about the partitions they induce.
What the condition say, is that the partition induced by $f$ refines the partition induced by $g$. Namely, a fiber of $g$ is the union of fibers of $f$.

So there is really no need to use AC here. Since $f$ induces a partition of the partition induced by $g$, it also induces that unique function you described.

In general, any type of finitary definition will not *really* depend on AC. Indeed, if you want to be explicit, simply define $$h=\{(f(x),g(x))\mid x\in X\}$$
Now the condition on $f$ and $g$ proves that this is a function and it is not hard to prove that it satisfies the needed conditions.